# Networking - Number of Bytes Sent Through Port

Tags: c#, networking, port, packet

I have the following code in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Networking
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---Connecting to a Host using a Specific Port---");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Attempting Connection...");
            Console.WriteLine();

            string hostname = "www.yahoo.com";
            int port_no = 21; //HTTP = 80, HTTPS = 443, FTP = 21

            IPAddress ipa = (IPAddress)Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname)[0];

            try
            {
                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                socket.Connect(ipa, port_no);

                if (socket.Connected == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The connection was successful!");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == 10061)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The connection was NOT successful!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the program attempts to connect to a particular website using a specific port number.

How can the program be modified so that I can know if data is being sent over a particular port after connection?  Maybe count the number of bytes sent or the type of file?  Thank you :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Do you want to send data from this program to yahoo, or are you interested in whether yahoo is going to send data to your program?

Comment: @DavinTryon I want to check how much data is being sent from my computer to yahoo.  I want to elaborate on this program to protect against keyloggers.  In other words, if data is being sent without the user's consent, then there might be a possibility that there is a keylogger or other malware installed.  Obviously, I will also check the FTP and email ports to make this possible.

Comment: Hmmm, are you worried about another process intercepting the network traffic?  Maybe you should look at securing the communication channel through TLS? [here's a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150597.aspx)

Comment: @DavidTryon Let me describe my scenario.  Let us assume that the host computer has a keylogger.  The keylogger can make use of the HTTP, FTP and email ports to send data to the attacker.  Let us assume that the keylogging program sends data through the SMTP port (port 25).  My program would sit as a windows service and detects if any data is being sent on the SMTP port.  The program then advises the user that data is being sent over the SMTP port and asks him if he is aware of this (much like a firewall).  If the user is effectively sending an email himself, no problems.  If not, the program

Comment: will give the user a number of options (I still have to think about these)

Comment: So effectively, I want a program which continuously listens on the HTTP, FTP and email ports and advises the user in case data is being sent.  To implement this, I need to check the size of the data as well.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you want to intercept network traffic in and out of the host.  Maybe you should look at [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) or [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/).

Comment: Since you are assuming to use a ftp for all transfers , you could use the equivalent of read function in C which returns the number of characters read. I mean receive all of the data into an array and count the characters received. Apart from this , what Matthew says would be better that your program should incorporate incoming outgoing from other ports too.

Comment: @KavishDwivedi I want to only monitor the data that is being sent from my computer only.  So essentially, I want to keep track of the data sent, not received.

Comment: @Matthew:write function does that equivalently. I shouldn't call them functions because they are actually nearer to system calls but yes I have written a lot of programs like sending some mathematical expression to the server and getting the result back . I used it to do it using read and write and sent and received the data in arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities. First you can call `Accept` on the socket and make your program block until data is available. As soon as data is available you can `Receive` data into a byte array and work on this.

Secondly you can call `BeginAccept` and asynchronously wait for data to arrive and handle it accordingly.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) on sockets in C#.